# how to display overlay width and height

Tags: modal-dialogs

hi i'm using overlay paths module with overlay module.  i have 2 questions

- how to set an overlay width , i tried as mynode/*|200px but it doesn't works.
- is it possible to view a page in a overlay without header and footer .

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/node/669378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your path in `admin/config/system/overlay_paths_ui` whit pattern like this `node/add|600px`. (I test it by myself, it effect after I clear cache in `admin/config/development/performance`  ).
This module cant help you to set a height for overlay.(you can patch this module to provide your require   ).
Final and good solution for do your job is **use css**, set css in your css file

```
#overlay {
height :xxx px; !important
width :xxx px; !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to modify the overlay when a specific node type (test) is displayed inside the overlay. The script re-size the overlay to 450px wide and also hide some unwanted items.

If you want to alter all the layouts no matter what, then [overlay.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!overlay!overlay.tpl.php/7) would be a better choice.

Declare your hook:

```
function mymodule_overlay_child_initialize() {
  // Add our custom JavaScript.
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/overlay-child.js');
}
```

Add the code to your JavaScript file:

```
(function ($) {
  // Adjust the overlay dimensions.
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $('#overlay:not(.mymodule-adjusted)', context).each(function() {
        var $test = $(this).find('.node-type-test');
        if ($test.length){
          // adjust the overlay
          $(this).css({
            'width'     : '450px',
            'min-width' : '450px'
          });
          $('.add-or-remove-shortcuts', this).hide();  // hide "add short-cut" button
          $('#branding', this).hide();  // hide branding container
        }
      }).addClass('mymodule-adjusted');
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

for more info check this [tutorial](https://drupal.org/node/1087026).